# Preloading Data Selected Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of products that my client has to choose from. The item is clicked and it is displayed on the  page where you can see the name and price.

I am able to display the selected items but it is not been arranged how i would want it.  When i select an item it displays like

```
Item : Facebook

Price :190
```

when i select the next item it displays like

```
Item : Facebook

Item : Google

Price :190

Price: 100
```

How can i arrange them in order like

```
Item : Facebook

Price :190

Item : Google

Price: 100
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="container">
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="amount"></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

when button is clicked

```
 $(".name").append(' Item : ' +item.name);  
 $(".amount").append('Price :' +item.amount);
```

Comment: And how do you want it to appear? Do you want to replace the existing content? If to just use .text() instead of .append()

Comment: You simply have to remove the previous item from the DOM with, for exemple; `$('.item').html('');` if I understand correctly

Comment: @ADyson please check the update on how i want it to be like

Comment: @3Dos, kindly check the update and look at how i want it to be like

Comment: ah ok. So you probably want to create two new `<p>` elements and append _those_ to the container element.

Comment: @ADyson, exactly what i want

Comment: Post a working snippet with html and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it as a complete string and append it to the container

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
   $(".container").append('<p class="name">Name:Facebook</p><p class="amount">Price:30</p>');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click</button>
<div class="container" id="container">
<p class="name"></p>
<p class="amount"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to fill the parent container with the data. Now you just add name into p.name and amount to p.amount

try to add another p.name and p.amount to the parent container.

```
$("#container").append("<p class=\"name\">"+item.name+"</p><p class=\"amount\">"+item.amount+"</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the format you want, you need to create two new `<p>` elements and append those to the container, rather than appending things to the existing paragraphs.

```js
$(function() {
  var item = {
    "name": "Google",
    "amount": "100"
  };

  $("#container").append(
    $("<p>", {
      "class": "name",
      "text": ' Item : ' + item.name
    }),
    $("<p>", {
      "class": "amount",
      "text": ' Price : ' + item.amount
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <p class="name">Item: Facebook</p>
  <p class="amount">Price: 190</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding new paragraphs inside the div like this:

Example:

```
function addItem() {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<p>Item : ' +item.name + '</p>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<p>Price :' +item.amount + '</p>';
}
```